# REGEX: how to make this statement become 2 match in REGEX

Tags: java, regex

I have statement: `<%=anything%><%=anything%>`

and a regular expression: `<%=\\s*(\\S+)\\s*%>`.

The regex matches the stament as 1 match instead of 2 matches.

Can someone fix my regex?

Btw I use Java for my application

Comment: Could you please tell, what language/tool you are using (looks a bit like java)? Also when I test it, `<%=\\s*(\\S+)\\s*%>` matches only `<%= anything %>`

Comment: sorry my bad, 
I mean <%=anything%><%=anything%>

I will edit it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently matching it all into one match, because regex usually is greedy, thus taking everything it can match into the match - so `=anything%><%=anything` is all matched by \S+. You could use the lazy modifier for the \S, so it matches as small as it has to, like so: `<%=\\s*(\\S+?)\\s*%>`. But there is an even better way to work with - as you don't want to match the closing `>`, just include it into a negative character class: `<%=\\s*([^\\s>]+)\\s*%>`

Here is a demo of it: https://regex101.com/r/bA4qY9/1 
Note that you might have to double the backslashes again after testing in regex101

If you want to read further into it, have a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Comment: Hi sebastian thank you very much,
your code perfectly work!!
Honestly i;am very newbie with REGEX.

Can u tell me the best site to learn REGEX?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ should be a great place to start. Glad it helped.

Comment: Thanks again for ur site recommendation :)

Comment: The statement *regex is usually greedy*  is not true. The `\S+` subpattern is greedy since the `+` is a greedy quantifier if no `?` follows it. However, greediness Iis only a part of the problem: `\S`  can match the angle brackets. Once you restrict it to `[^\s>]` you can go on using greedy plus and the results will be the expected ones.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Would rewording it to "regex repetition is usually greedy" suit your needs?

Comment: @SebastianProske Hi sebastian, can you explain to me the function of "^\\s". Because if i remove that string, REGEX still works.

Thank you

Comment: @Kim `[^\\s>]` matches everything that's not a whitespace or a closing angle bracket - the check for no whitespaces was part of your initial regex `(\\S)`, so I included it. Of course you can also match only everything, thats no closing angle bracket by using `[^>]`